# GitHub Pagesでサブモジュールのコンテンツを表示したい。

Tags: html, github

GitHub Pagesのレポジトリに別のレポジトリに存在するHugoで作成した静的コンテンツをサブモジュールとして追加しました。

```
├── README.md
├── blog //サブモジュール。なかにはHugoで作成される静的コンテンツが含まれている
├── css
├── images
├── index.html
└── js
```

しかし、`<username>.github.io/blog/`でページが表示されません。Github pagesでサブモジュールのコンテンツを表示するにはどのようにすればいいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しました。

.gitmoduleファイルのurlを`https://github.com/<username>/<repositoryname>.git`に変更したところ実現できました。

その後`git submodule sync`コマンドを使い.gitディレクトリのURLを更新しました。